# iPhone UITextField within TableCell blanking out

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

In my iPhone app I have a settings page where a user can enter text into multiple TextFields.  The text fields are all cells within a table.  The problem I'm noticing is that when a field scrolls off the phone's screen it loses the value currently in the text field.

I notice Apple's apps always have you click on a field to edit it, which brings up a new view with just that field as a text box.  Seems like pointless extra clicks, I'm hoping to find a way to allow for a table with UITextFields to preserve their values, even when they scroll of screen.

I do have an event bound to when the user presses the Next/Done button on the keyboard (didFinishEditingField:) to update a value within the table controller, but if they don't press that and the just tap inside another field that isn't triggered.

How can I make sure the values aren't blanked out when I scroll the table and fields leave the current screen?

**Edit:** For clarification the reason I went with the UITextFields inside of a table and cells, instead of all in one view, is because I wanted it to look like the typical settings page with the stripped background and the groups of inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that u arent reusing cells properly give all ur textfield cells unique reusable ids Check out my answer herehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180490/iphone-custom-uitableviewcell-with-image-after-scroll/1180817#1180817

Answer (score 1):

Are you reusing cells? Moreover, to create your initial cell do you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`? I've tried something similar, and it turns out that reusing cells, then adding editable fields to them, produces unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and was not dequeuing cells.  Uniquely identifying the cells is confirmed to work.